# To send message through whatsapp

Tags: android, url, android-intent, onclick, whatsapp

Using `Intent` with WhatsApp `URL`, I get a pre-filled message to contact but I have to click on send button. Is there any way to send the message automatically? Can't we press the send button pro-grammatically using Android?

Comment: There is no Direct Way .. Indirect Way is Accessibility Service.

Comment: Have you checked `performClick()` method of `Button`? Also please share your efforts, codes to prove this question useful.

Comment: String text = "Hi";
String toNumber = "91xxxxxxxxxx";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+toNumber +"&text="+text));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: @ADM Apart from this I tried this with enabling accessibility service to send the message by indirectly pressing the button, for the first time when I launch my app it works i.e "sends the message",but after that only the above part is executed.

Comment: Above is the code which I used to get the prefilled text: @AbhinavSaxena and I tried to use accessibility service to send the message. I didn't try performClick() does it works?Could you share some link regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to send text in whatsapp

- Using Url
- Using Intent

In both cases users have to click send button explicitly to send the message.

So as of now it is not possible to send message directly without clicking send button.